# Android Studio java-library module classpath NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, module

My project is started to be large, so I decided to split it into separated modules - `gui` and `domain`. My `domain` module mustn't know that it is a part of Android project, so I created `java-library` module and put some classes there. It works like a charm but there is a problem when I add some other dependencies inside my `java-library` module like RxJava. I've created a `Main` class to simply test my code. Builds passes, but when it tries to invoke RxJava classes it crashes with exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/Observable
    at com.example.domain.Main.main(Main.java:13)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.reactivex.Observable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

My Main class:

```
package com.example.domain;

import io.reactivex.Observable;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable.just(1)
                .subscribe(integer -> System.out.println(integer));
    }

}
```

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

1) If I use `com.android.library` instead it works

2) If I add RxJava library as a `.jar` file it changes nothing

### EDIT:

I looked into `Domain.iml` file and I found something strange:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":Domain" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.." external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":Domain" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="java-gradle" name="Java-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="BUILD_FOLDER_PATH" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
        <option name="BUILDABLE" value="true" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/java/main" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/java/test" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="rxjava-2.1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="reactive-streams-1.0.0" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

The weird part is `scope` attribute in `orderEntry` node

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="rxjava-2.1.2" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="reactive-streams-1.0.0" level="project" />
```

If I remove it manually:

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="rxjava-2.1.2" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="reactive-streams-1.0.0" level="project" />
```

It works like a charm.

Unfortunately if I sync my `build.gradle` file it overrides my modification.

How to make it works permanently and why this acts like this?

Comment: What version of java-library plugin are you using? Is it possible that the plugin is outdated and it does not recognize "api" dependency type?

Comment: Changing "api" to "implementation" or even "compile" changes nothing

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, you have imported `Observable` into your class, right?

Comment: Yes I did. IDE recognizes RxJava because it auto-complete my code

Comment: Is you Main class big? Why don't you include the whole thing so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: So, it builds but it does not run. (Your gradle file is used for building, and hence it's not gradle file issue.) What kind of IDE are you using? Android Studio? It'll likely have something to do with your run time classpath. Seems like your IDE sets the classpath differently based on whether it's an android app or just a java app...

Comment: Yes, I'm using Android Studio - It's in the title. Version 3.0 to be precise

Comment: Hmm.. I take it back. I just recall the runtime classpath generally inherits from build time classpath. Hence, your runtime classpath should include rxjava. But, apparently it doesn't...

Comment: @Lau Can I know what version of gradle and android gradle plugin are you using? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 Sure. Gradle Version 4.1; Android Plugin Version 3.0.1

Comment: @Lau Thanks. I am using the same versions. I have added the dependencies in the 'main' outer module for now. It's a workaround but works for now.

Comment: I know this isn't much help but I also seeing this on a large production application as well. I thought it was a multidex issue but I am unsure now as I have followed all the proper steps to implement it. I added some modules from another branch and everything works in test but when it comes to actually running it, when Foo.class is accessed I get the same error.

Comment: Also getting the same error with Android Studio 3.1.2. Tried everything, even changed Android embedded jdk to the system jdk...

Answer (score 0):

> The weird part is scope attribute in orderEntry node
>
> ```
> <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="rxjava-2.1.2" level="project" />
> <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="reactive-streams-1.0.0" level="project" />
> ```
>
> If I remove it manually:
>
> ```
> <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="rxjava-2.1.2" level="project" />
> <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="reactive-streams-1.0.0" level="project" />
> ```
>
> It works like a charm.
>
> Unfortunately if I sync my build.gradle file it overrides my
>   modification.

Have you tried to change the scope via Android Studios Project Structure?

File -> Project Structure then select the Dependencies Tab and add the Dependency for the required module. In your case that would be ***java-library*** I believe.

As far as i know you can't change the scope of the dependency once added. So if you have already added it, try to remove and add it again. Be sure to assign the implementation scope though and see if it works.

I hope this was helpful